# How to change OData root service uri

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, metadata, odata

I have an OData service. The base root uri is: http://example.com/odata/v1.
I expose it through another site: http://apigee.com/odata/v1. This site redirects all requests to example.com and has client verification mechanism.

I am using the OData .NET client library to call the service. Every simple request works fine:

```
GET http://apigee.com/odata/v1/Activities(1)
GET http://apigee.com/odata/v1/AppPackages(1)
```

The corresponding .NET code is like this:

```
var container = new Container("http://apigee.com/odata/v1");
var activity = container.Activities.Where(p => p.id == "1").SingleOrDefault();
var apppackage = container.AppPackages.Where(p => p.id == "1").SingleOrDefault();
```

When I want to add link between these two entities, I run into "Unauthorization" problem. The code is:

```
 container.AddLink(act, "AppPackages", package);
 container.SaveChanges();
```

And the generated http request is:

```
POST http://example.com/odata/v1/Activities(1)/$links/AppPackages
```

The AddLink calls directly on "http://example.com/odata/v1" instead of "http://apigee.com/odata/v1". It does not pass through the client verification on apigee.com so example.com rejects it. I guess the reason is from the "odata.metadata". When I do

```
GET http://mysite.io/odata/v1/Activities(1)
```

The returned info is:

```
{
   "odata.metadata":"http://example.com/odata/v1/$metadata#Activities/@Element",
   ...
}
```

I wonder if there is a way for me to return "http://apigee.com/odata/v1" here. Or any way that can fix this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That Url is controlled by MetadataDocumentUri from ODataMessageWriterSettings.

If using ODataLib directly, you can try:

```
settings.SetMetadataDocumentUri(new Uri("http://apigee.com/odata/v1/$metadata"));
```

If using WCF Data Service, you can try override OnStartProcessingRequest method on your DataService:

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
{
    args.ServiceUri = new Uri("http://apigee.com/odata/v1/");
}
```